Copy or Sync all the repo branches from one Org Repo to another org with automation
I have written the powershell script which will sync or copy the repo from one org to another org, but currently this script is sync only master branch, but not all the branches.
Below is the Code
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Sync the Repo one from Org to another Org.
 
.DESCRIPTION
    Repo or Detla sync of entire repo from Org to another org 
    using Powershell script.
#>
 
#Clear Console
Clear-Host
 
# Delete the Old Destination Folder
$Path = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(API_Repo)\"
if (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {
    # Get all files in the folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
    # Loop through each file and delete it
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force
        Write-Output "Deleted: $($file.Name)"
        }
}
 
#Source URL to fetch the Repo
$Sourceurl = "https://$(SourceOrg):$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/$(SourceOrg)/$(URLSourceProject)/_git/$(API_Repo)"
 
#Destination URL to push the Repo
$DestinationURL = "https://$(DestinationOrg):$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/$(DestinationOrg)/$(DestinationProject)/_git/$(API_Repo)"
 
#Set Location for current folder
Set-Location "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"

Write-Output "***** Cloning the Source URL*****"
git clone $Sourceurl
 
#Set Location to get the latest repo from source
Write-Output "Source Project: $(API_Repo)"

Set-Location "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(API_Repo)\"
Write-Output "*****Git removing remote origin****"
 
#Git Commands to fetch and push the code
git remote rm origin
 
Write-Output "*****Git remote add****"
git remote add --mirror=fetch origin $DestinationURL
 
# Git Commands to fetch all branches and push them to the destination repo
Write-Output "*****Git fetch all branches****"

# Create and switch to a temporary branch
git checkout -b temp_branch

# Fetch all branches from the source repository
git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"

# Loop through each branch and push it to the destination repo
git branch -r | ForEach-Object {
    $branch = $_
    if ($branch -like "*remotes*" -and $branch -notlike "*HEAD*") {
        git checkout $branch.Replace("remotes/origin/", "")
        git pull
    }
}

# Finally, push all tags to the destination repo
Write-Output "*****Git push tags to destination repo****"
git push -u origin --tags --force

# Switch back to the master branch
git checkout master

In the ADO the task is getting completed successfully without any errors but when i check the destination side i dont see any branches on the repo got copied or synced from Source.
ADO Task Output
******Git removing remote origin****
*****Git remote add****
*****Git fetch all branches****
Switched to a new branch 'temp_branch'
branch 'temp_branch' set up to track 'origin/master'.
From https://dev.azure.com/org/Project/_git/Test.Api
 * [new branch]        master     -> origin/master
*****Git push tags to destination repo****
Everything up-to-date
Switched to branch 'master'

